# Visual Studio 2022 warns "'xxx' may be null here" even when there is no possible way `xxx` could be null

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a C# method (net6.0) similar to this:

```
bool TryDoSomething(out MyObject1? obj1, out MyObject2? obj2)
{
    obj1 = DoSomethingElse();
    obj2 = DoAnotherThing();
   
    //Do some other things....
    
    return obj1 != null && obj2 != null;
}
```

This is called by another method thusly:

```
bool CallingMethod()
{
    if (!TryDoSomething(out var obj1, out var obj2))
        return false;

    obj1.PerformSomeAction();
    obj2.PerformADifferentAction();
    
    //Do many other things....
    
    return true;

}
```

As is clear from the definition of `TryDoSomething()` and the fact that I am exiting early with `return false`, there is no way that `obj1` or `obj2` could be `null` by the time `obj1.PerformSomeAction()` or `obj2.PerformADifferentAction()` are called (the method would have returned early due to `TryDoSomething()` returning `false` before reaching those lines).

Yet, despite this, Visual Studio shows a squiggly line under `obj1` and `obj2` informing me that `'xxx' may be null here`.....`Dereference of a possibly null reference`. (where 'xxx' is either 'obj1' or 'obj2').

How can this be happening?  Is it a bug with Visual Studio itself?

Comment: and FYI you could have looked up any Tryxxx method of .net in source code eg. int.TryParse https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/3b4f8469bf036c4163a8f9cb15bfa888e10ce9ab/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Int32.cs#L157

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the first method with attributes:

```cs
bool TryDoSomething([NotNullWhen(true)] out MyObject1? obj1, [NotNullWhen(true)] out MyObject2? obj2)
{
...
}
```

Inside your `CallingMethod()`, analysis makes no attempt at understanding the inner workings of the *other* method, `TryDoSomething(...)`. So if there is some connection between the return value and the null state of the parameters, than must be communicated with attributes.

Read [Attributes for null-state static analysis interpreted by the C# compiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis) to learn more about this.